# Changing radio buttons to dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce

I'm trying to change radio buttons to dropdowns using css. The site is built on wordpress but is it possible to change the radio buttons to dropdowns using only css or do i need to add javascript somewhere?

So my end game is to change "delivery" radio buttons to a dropdown. They have their own class.

When i search it keeps coming back to this code. Am i missing something here or is it a case of i should forget about the dropdown?

```
<div class="wcsatt-options-wrapper" <?php echo count( $options ) === 1 ? 'style="display:none;"' : '' ?>><?php

if ( $prompt ) {
    echo $prompt;
} else {
    ?><h3><?php
        _e( 'Choose a subscription plan:', 'woocommerce-subscribe-all-the-things' );
    ?></h3><?php
}

?><ul class="wcsatt-options-product"><?php
    foreach ( $options as $option ) {
        ?><li class="<?php echo esc_attr( $option[ 'class' ] ); ?>">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="convert_to_sub_<?php echo absint( $product_id ); ?>" data-custom_data="<?php echo esc_attr( json_encode( $option[ 'data' ] ) ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $option[ 'value' ] ); ?>" <?php checked( $option[ 'selected' ], true, true ); ?> />
                <?php echo '<span class="' . esc_attr( $option[ 'class' ] ) . '-details">' . $option[ 'description' ] . '</span>'; ?>
            </label>
        </li><?php
    }
?></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the "ul" tag with following code.

```
<select class="anyting-you-wish" name="convert_to_sub_<?php echo absint( $product_id ); ?>">
    <?php foreach ( $options as $option ) { ?>
        $selected = ($option[ 'selected' ] == true ? 'selected="selected"' : null);
        <option data-custom_data="<?php echo esc_attr( json_encode( $option[ 'data' ] ) ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $option[ 'value' ] ); ?>" <?php echo($selected); ?> >
            <?php echo($option[ 'description' ]); ?>
        </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Kindly let me know if this works.

Comment: Spot on making it all dropdown :) however it breaks the function which tells the DB it's a subscription model. :(

Comment: So there is two options one is a "one off delivery" the other will be subscription with options added afterwards such as every 1 week, every 2 weeks, every 3 weeks. When i select the every options it only adds it as a one off.

Comment: It sounds like "click" or "change" action on the radio button. Like, when the respective radio button is selected display further options. In that case, you have to write some javascript on select change event to correspond to the previous functionality. Does this make sense?

Comment: I understand it slightly. But not great at javascript. This was done by someone who I can no longer get hold of :( Is it something easy to do? or will it take a fair bit of javascript?  I Found this script online while hunting a dropdown from radio script. https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Checkbox-Radio-Inputs-To-Dropdown-jQuery.html

Comment: This is not just about converting radio button to dropdown. It has further connected functionality. It will need fair bit of javascript knowledge. Also, it will need fair knowledge of woocommerce subscription plugin (I can only guess that subscription plugin is used). Is there any accessible URL to check?

Comment: its all offline at the moment. but can drop you a link of the packages it uses if thats easier.
The two plugins for woocommerce. https://drive.google.com/open?id=12lt8HZRBgQKoRGtF7UnlAHHu29RGXno1